# django-autocomplete-light - what JS files to include in my template?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I am going crazy. I just installed django-autocomplete-light and it doesn't seem obvious from the [docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#django-autocomplete-light-tutorial) (or from existing SO posts or [issues](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues) on the repo), which js files to include in my template.

I have a simple usecase where I want to display a ManytoManyField in the ModelSelect2Multiple widget:

```
class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = ['name', 'area', 'type', 'locations',]
        widgets = {
            'area': CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'locations': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(),
        }
```

What JS files do I include in my template for the widget to show up?

Comment: Have your get any idea?

Comment: @Italo, no, I moved on and used [Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) instead